# Are there anything special about IP ranges 2.x.x.x and 90.x.x.x?

Tags: web-server, ip

Some of our users are unable to connect to one particular web server (our library catalogue), getting an "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to..." type message across all browsers. The only thing they seem to have in common is that their IP addresses are all in the range 2.x.x.x or 90.x.x.x from the same ISP.

I vaguely recall the 2.x range having some historical significance but can't find any reference to it.

Comment: the 2. range was only assigned in 2009, so it may be you remember it not being so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Addresses on the 2.0.0.0/8 network used to be so-called [Bogons / Fullbogons](http://www.team-cymru.org/Services/Bogons/). The network is not on the [current Fullbogon list](http://www.team-cymru.org/Services/Bogons/fullbogons-ipv4.txt) any more and has been [assigned to RIPE](http://www.ripe.net/), so its addresses are valid nowadays, but some admins might still use [obsolete data](http://www.stearns.org/modwall/sample/bogons-sample) for filtering, thus your trouble.

Check with the network admin responsible for the connectivity of your library catalogue, he should be either able to help directly or escalate it upstream.

Comment: Thanks syneticon-dj. We can't find any sign of filtering going on and there were other instances of 2.x.x.x IP addresses in the access logs so looks like I'll have to keep looking. You answered the question though :¬)